# How to fix the provisioning profile error using a wildcard

Tags: xcode, wildcard, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

- Main goal: To have two builds of the same application on my phone.
- What I've done: Switched the provisioning profile to "wildcard" from "DEV" and changed the bundle identifier to "com.mycompany.*" from "com.mycompany.appname".

I ran it, and I get an error that says

"(null): error: CFBundleIdentifier 'com.mycompany.*' contains illegal character " * " invalid bundle identifier 'com.mycompany.*'"

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wildcard in Bundle Identifier. Instead if you have an app id com.company.* and your provisioning profile with that App id. Use that provisioning profile to sign your app and install on device. If you want another instance of the app on the device, change the bundle identifier of your app which doesn't match with first bundle identifier and install it on device.